# How to buil a clickable custom map using path and region in Android

Tags: android, path, dictionary, shapes, region

To explain my problem, I am going to start from a case study that is not what I have to do but which will give you a good idea of what I am talking about.

Imagine the map of the US in which you have the states / provinces. Each of these provinces has got a shape that is random (by random I mean it is not a rectangle, a triangle or a circle). I need to build these shapes independantly, size them correctly and put them at the correct place on the screen to represent the country. Finally, each of these province should be clickable.

To achieve that :

1) I don't want to use google map

2) I guess that I'll have to construct each provine using android path and android region ... can you confirm?

3) Is there a graphical tool for building these paths (photoshop import ?)

4) Assuming that I succeed to build the path, how can I put them at the correct place on the screen ?

5) How can I make these path clickable ?

Basically, I want to build an interactive map with clickable items that doesn't use Google map because it won't necessarly be a real map.

Thanks for your help,

R.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of variables in the problem you describe:

1. If you don't want to use google-maps, you'll need to use another engine. There are a few open-source ones available.
2. If you feel you don't need a map engine, you'll need to provide you're own image of the US to draw on an pin the image to the View
3. How do you plan to draw the boundaries? Do you have coordinate data for the boundaries or do you plan to draw them manually.

I would suggest first looking at openstreetmap: http://www.openstreetmap.org/  The have a lot of information and tools on creating Maps.  From there you can attack adding to the phone. Or you can use their web api and build a web view for doing what you suggest.

Comment: Thx for your answer dbryson ! I actually don't want a map engine bescause I have all the images that compose the map that I have to build and it doesn't respect any "real" map. Let's say it is a map of a virtual world in a game. The key point here is to know how to transform my images (one image per clickable region) into android path and then, place my path correctly on the screen. Is there any graphical tool for building path in android ? Can I import layers from photoshop ? I just don't get how can I easily create custom interactive area in Android.